# while loop requires explicit condition, for loop doesn't, why?

Tags: c++, loops, syntax

In C++ you are allowed to have an empty condition inside the for-loop, for example as in `for (;;)` or `for (int x = 0;; ++x)`. But you can't do `while ()`.

When condition is omitted inside the for loop, condition is assumed to be `true` (so the loop loops forever). Why isn't this the case with `while` loops, that is, what's the argument behind not letting `while ()` be an alias of `while (true)`?

Comment: The answer is likely 2-fold:  1) to be backwards compatible with C99, and 2) because the standards committee said so.  There may be some grammar reason why `while()` may not work, but theoretically that could have been fixed if they really wanted it to be.

Comment: @ZacHowland 1) Then the question is why this is the case in C99 ;)

Comment: @leemes - Because the C90 standards committee said so ;)

Comment: This question isn't opinion based, the OP is asking if there exists a reason for this oddity.  The answer is either "yes: because X", or "not really".  One is true, and the other is false.  What's subjective about that?

Comment: @MooingDuck "What is the argument behind not letting `while()` be an alias of `while(true)`?" - that is opinion based as there isn't really an argument for it - it just is.

Comment: @ZacHowland: He asked "Why is it the case", and the answer is probably "Because the C90 standards committee said so, there isn't any argument for it", which is not subjective at all.

Comment: It is mandated by design of the C language, see my post

Comment: `#define while(c) for(;c;)` That should "fix" it ;) (jk, will not even work correctly)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Presumably, it's a side-effect of the fact that each given clause within the for-statement is optional. There's reasons why some for-loops wouldn't need an assignment; there's reasons why some others wouldn't need a condition; there's reasons why still others wouldn't need an increment. Requiring there to be some minimum number of them would be needlessly-added complexity.

Comment: This answers why `for(;;)` is valid, but does not address why `while()` cannot be (which likely would be opinion based).

Comment: The point is that they didn't set out to make conditions optional in control statements in general. It was purely a matter of consistency within the special case of the for-loop.

Comment: @ZacHowland the only reason to make `while()` work without a condition would be to express the common idiom of an endless loop (or ended by jumping out). Since `for(;;)` already expresses that idiom, there's no need to change the syntax for `while()`.

Comment: There are at least 3 interpretations of my question, one would be what the Standard says (6.8.5.3); was there and if yes what was (historically) the reason behind this decision in the Standard of C (of course, the historical reason for inclusion in C++ (not C) Standard is backward compatibility); and is there a good argument for these design decisions regardless of whether that argument also historically made designers of langague have them included. Since the third  seems to me to be the most important, and Sneftel's answer is very strong, convincing and intuitive, I accept this answer.

Answer (score 8):

The following is from the book **Deep C Secrets**:

*Early C had no separate operators for & and && or | and ||. (Got that?) Instead it used the notion (inherited from B and BCPL) of "truth-value context": where a Boolean value was expected, after "if" and "while" and so forth, the & and | operators were interpreted as && and || are now; in ordinary expressions, the bitwise interpretations were used. It worked out pretty well, but was hard to explain. (There was the notion of "top-level operators" in a truth-value context.)*

So there you have it, `while()` would set the context for a truth value and can't be empty or implied for the same reason if() can't be empty, the mechanics of the early language expected them not to be.

Comment: I don't get it. What does the meaning of the operators, and the "context" have to do with the question if the expression is *optional*?

Comment: To implement the 'truth-value-context' in C (as in B and BCPL) a boolean value was expected after if() and while() ... so they can't be empty. Even though the original reason (dissambiguation of the meaning of & as & or && etc) is not present anymore, the design was passed on to newer versions of C and then to C++.

Comment: Still don't get why this is an argument. They could said that **if** there is something within the parentheses, it's a boolean expression context. Also, why doesn't the same count for `for` loops?

Comment: Yes they could but they didn't, that's what a design choice is. You don't need to understand anything there, don't trouble yourself. I simply present the history of it, which explains what the original reasons where to have a boolean value expected after `while()` and `if()`. The case of `for` differs in that there are 3 contexes present "declaration - truth value - ammendment", not a single one.

Answer (score 8):

> In C++ you are allowed to have an empty condition inside the for-loop ... 
>   what's the argument behind not letting `while()` be an alias of `while(true)`?

First of all, C++ (and C# and many other languages) are the way they are for backwards compatibility with C, so let's talk about C.

Let's make some statements and draw a conclusion.

1. There is a good reason why the `for` loop allows you to omit the condition.
2. The same good reason applies to the `while` loop.
3. The `while` loop does not allow the condition to be omitted; it is inconsistent.
4. Consistency of design choices across statements is an important factor in the design of C.
5. Therefore there must be an unobvious good reason for the inconsistency; there must be a good reason why the `while` loop is inconsistent with the `for` loop.

And now the question is "what is that unobvious good reason?"

But the question only makes sense if the chain of logic described above is correct, which it is not.  Of those statements, only #3 is actually true! The `for` loop in C is a poor design; it's redundant, confusing for novices and its lexical conventions are inconsistent with the rest of the language. It provides almost zero additional representational power to the language over a straightforward `while` loop.

There is no answer to your question; **the correct response is rather to reject the premise of the question entirely.** The `for` loop only seems reasonable because it's a 40+ year old misfeature that most of us grew up with, so its quirks are second nature now; this is familiarity, not good design. Had we grown up without the `for` loop, we wouldn't be adding it.

Comment: And yet recently, range-based for-loops *were* added, indicating a distinct appetite for a loop designed to express iteration over a sequence. Its semantics may be a bit hairy, but I think that's more a matter of the limitations of C's ability to abstract sequences than it is of the advisability of including the feature in general.

Comment: @Sneftel: Oh don't get me wrong; I love the idea of a loop that abstracts over the operation of iterating over a sequence. The fundamental problem with the `for` loop is that its syntax is *so goofy*. The semicolon can logically be thought of as the *sequential composition of side effects operator*. When you say `A(); B(); C();` in C, that means to sequentially compose the side effects of the three function calls. That's what it means everywhere except in a foreach loop, where it means something very different.

Comment: That's a good point. It would be interesting if they had made the syntax `for(a)(b)(c) { ... }`, or even `for {a}{c}(b) {...}`. After all, `a` and `c`, in a sense, deserve to be blocks, and `b` deserves not to be.

Comment: @Sneftel: That would be a start. The braces though would be confused with scopes which is unfortunate. I say use awesome invention called words to improve clarity. By simply replacing `;` with words we get much clarity. How about `do (initializer while expression by statement) statement` -- `do (node* p = head while p != NULL by p = p->next;)...`.  is in the spirit of C syntax without overloading the meaning of `;`.

Answer (score 3):

I think the main difference is between *expressions* and *statements*.

Sure, in C the two aren't rigorously distinguished, but I would say the for loop is:

```
for (statement; expression; statement) {
    ...
}
```

The expression is a boolean expression, while the statements are...statements which have side effects. Of course, C isn't semi-functional; you can put side effects in the middle expression, but it isn't idiomatic.

Yet sometimes you don't want an expression, but statements at the beginning and at each loop iteration is useful, so the middle expression is optional:

```
// Infinite counter
int i;
for (i = 0;;i++) {
   ...
}
```

This by definition means that the expression is considered always true

On the other hand, `while` and `if` can *only* take expressions. There is nothing very useful left (unlike the two useful statements left) if you omit that expression: nobody would write

```
// Idiot coding
if (true) {
   ...
}
```

because the point of an `if` statement is to check whether some unknown is true or not!

Same thing with `while`. The point of `while` is to do something over and over as long as a *condition* in the form of an expression is true. It's kinda like an "iterated `if`". This is why

```
while() {
   ...
}
```

is not considered logical and thus not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [Document](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) :

**6.8.5.3 The for statement**

> The statement `for ( clause-1 ; expression-2 ; expression-3 )`
>   statement behaves as follows:
>
> 1. The expression expression-2 is the controlling expression that is
>      evaluated before each execution of the loop body. The expression
>      expression-3 is evaluated as a void expression after each execution
>      of the loop body. If clause-1 is a declaration, the scope of any
>      identiﬁers it declares is the remainder of the declaration and the
>      entire loop, including the other two expressions; it is reached in
>      the order of execution before the ﬁrst evaluation of the controlling
>      expression. If clause-1 is an expression, it is evaluated as a void
>      expression before the ﬁrst evaluation of the controlling
>      expression.158)
> 2. Both clause-1 and expression-3 can be omitted. **An omitted
>      expression-2 is replaced by a nonzero constant.**

So, in case of `for` loop, condition will be replaced by non-zero constant and no such implementation for `while` loop.

Comment: OP wanted to know the reasons behind this text from the Standard; I assume he already knows C/C++ syntax

Comment: Right. And the original question was basically, why is an omitted conditional allowed in the second expression of a for-statement, but not in the condition of a while-statement? He already knows the rules, he wanted to know the reasoning used by the people writing those words you copied.

Answer (score -3):

The difference between logical statements used in while() and for(;;) loops is that:

- in case of for the statement defines **condition of exiting the loop**
- in case of while() the statement defines **condition of executing the loop**

Assuming that, you see that to enter a loop, you need at least a condition of executing, not a condition of exiting.

Comment: `for` loop's syntax contains a condition for executing the loop, just like the `while` loop's syntax