# Check for null pointer in a truth-value context

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11

Lets say I have a pointer

```
MyType *ptr;
```

When checking the validity of that pointer in a ["truth-value context"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21713259/2567683) by the old standards I would write something like this

```
if (ptr)    { ... // 1
while (ptr) { ... // 2
```

The thing is that in such "truth value contexes" we expect for the implicit conversion of a pointer to a boolean value to take place, so we would be pretty much be comparing

```
if (NULL != ptr)    { ...
while (NULL != ptr) { ...
```

Yet comparing against a macro for the integer `0` is deprecated and C++11 proposes comparing against `nullptr`.

When in a truth value context though like (1) or (2) above where we don't explicitly say

```
if (nullptr != ptr) { ...
while (nullptr != ptr) { ...
```

**what is our pointer compared against ?** It's conversion to a boolean ? **Do we have to explicitly compare against `nullptr` ?**

Comment: Have you read [conv.bool]? http://stackoverflow.com/q/17772103/420683

Comment: @dyp No, I'm reading Bjarne's book and I see that everywhere he says `if (nullptr != ptr)` and that got me to think

Comment: All of above is valid and I guess none of the future standards will break it (Besides, never say never)

Comment: I'm not sure whether to close it as a dup or provide a better answer here.... besides the boolean conversion, there's [stmt.select]/4 which states that the condition of an if-statement is contextually converted to `bool` which then triggers the boolean conversion.

Comment: The other thread is way too cluttered to provide an answer that will clarify things. I'd propose the second

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The condition (if it's an expression) of an `if` statement is *contextually converted to `bool`*:

[stmt.select]/4 about the condition in selection statements (`if`, `switch`):

> The value of a condition that is an expression is the value of the
>   expression, contextually converted to `bool` for statements other than `switch`; if that conversion is ill-formed, the program is ill-formed.

*Contextual conversion to `bool`* is defined as follows in [conv]/3:

> An expression `e` can be *implicitly converted* to a type `T` if and only if the declaration `T t=e;` is well-formed, for some invented temporary variable `t`. Certain language constructs require that an expression be
>   converted to a Boolean value. An expression `e` appearing in such a context is said to be contextually converted to `bool` and is well-formed if and only if the declaration `bool t(e);` is well-formed, for some invented temporary variable `t`.

Here's the description of a conversion to `bool` for fundamental types [conv.bool]/1:

> A prvalue of arithmetic, unscoped enumeration, pointer, or pointer to member type can be converted to a
>   prvalue of type `bool`. A zero value, null pointer value, or null member pointer value is converted to `false`;
>   any other value is converted to `true`. A prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t` can be converted to a prvalue of
>   type `bool`; the resulting value is `false`.

So when we test a pointer `if(ptr)`, we compare `ptr` to the *null pointer value* of that type. What's a *null pointer value*? [conv.ptr]/1

> A *null pointer constant* is an integral constant expression prvalue of integer type that evaluates to
>   zero or a prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t`. A null pointer constant can be converted to a pointer type; the
>   result is the *null pointer value* of that type and is distinguishable from every other value of object pointer or
>   function pointer type. Such a conversion is called a *null pointer conversion*. Two null pointer values of the
>   same type shall compare equal.

This also describes what happens when we compare `if(ptr != nullptr)`: The `nullptr` is converted to the type of `ptr` (see [expr.rel]/2), and yields the *null pointer value* of that type. Hence, the comparison is *equivalent* to `if(ptr)`.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have:

```
int* ip = foo();
if ( nullptr == ip )
{
}
```

It's as if you are saying:

```
int* ip = foo();
if ( (int*)0 == ip )
{
}
```

At that point, you are comparing two pointers of the same type.

This is what I found at [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr)

> **Explanation**
>
> The keyword nullptr denotes the null pointer literal. It is an unspecified prvalue of type std::nullptr_t. There exist implicit conversions from nullptr to null pointer value of any pointer type and any pointer to member type. Similar conversions exist for any value of type std::nullptr_t as well as for the macro NULL, the null pointer constant.